# How can I remove this weird outline around my element?

Tags: html, css

I am getting a weird outline like something around my button for this styles. Why is it happening?

```css
button {
  padding: 1em;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}
button:focus {
  border-radius: 6px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 4px blue;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for some specific design reason, @Yuvaraj M's answer doesn't cover your case, consider using `inset` shadow for the white part.

```css
button {
  padding: 1em;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}

button:focus {
  border-radius: 6px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 2px blue;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```